# Access Microsoft Dataverse from Spring boot using Rest API

Tags: spring-boot, azure, oauth-2.0, odata, microsoft-dynamics

I am currently in the process of connecting a Spring Boot application with Microsoft Dataverse.

The following requirements exist

- CRUD operations in Dataverse tables
- Users to log in to the Spring application using OAuth2 via the Microsoft account.

Attached is a sequence diagram to illustrate this
[Sequence diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBBKi.png)
Unfortunately, I am failing with a 401 Unauthorized on the final access to a dataverse table.

I have done the following so far

1. entered the web application in Azure "App-Registration".
   [App Registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfhej.png)
2. generated client ID and client secret in Azure "App-Registration
   [Client Secrect & ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y1mE.png)
3. set the API Rights to Dynamics CRM and Microsoft Graph in Azure "App-Registration".
   [API Access rights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHS2k.png)
4. Entered the app user in the Power Apps Admin area and gave access to the corresponding table via the role.
   [App User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbkGy.png)

Furthermore I have created the following code

1. dependencies in Maven

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-reactive-httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

2. application.yaml

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory:
        enabled: true
        profile.tenant-id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
        credential:
          client-id: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
          client-secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        application-type: web-application
        authorization-clients:                
          graph:
            authorizationGrantType: client-credentials
            scopes:
              https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
          dynamics:
            authorizationGrantType: client-credentials            
            scopes:
              https://xxxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/.default
```

3. rest service

```
import static org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.oauth2AuthorizedClient;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.annotation.RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.ResponseSpec;

import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.transport.logging.AdvancedByteBufFormat;

@RestController
public class DataverseRestController {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService manager;

    @GetMapping("/graph")
    @ResponseBody
    public String produkte(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient client) {
        if (null == client) {
            return "Get response failed.";
        }

        RequestHeadersUriSpec<?> requestHeadersUriSpec = webClient.get();
        ResponseSpec response = requestHeadersUriSpec
                .uri("https://xxxxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/cr2a0_xxxxxxxxx")
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(client)).retrieve();
        String body = response.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        return "Get response " + (null != body ? "successfully" : "failed");
    }

}
```

4. webclient config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.transport.logging.AdvancedByteBufFormat;

@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction function = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient",
                io.netty.handler.logging.LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).apply(function.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
}
```

I could make the following observations

1. it is strange, if I log in with my standard user, which has access to the table, I cannot call the table via the Rest API (401). If I log in normally as an admin, I can't either (401). However, if I go to the Power Platform Admin Center in the environment and call up the environment URL there via the link, I have to log in again even though I am already authenticated as an admin. Afterwards I can also call up the data of the table in Dataverse from the browser with the same URL. [Link where I logged in an then the tables are shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXCCa.png)
2. when calling the rest interface I can't specify the authorised client which is configured in the application.yaml. @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient and @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("azure") work. @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("dynamics") does not. Here comes null
3. the web application correctly forwards the unauthenticated user to Microsoft and the necessary data is also forwarded to the application as a token.

Can someone here possibly help and clarify what I am doing wrong?

My guess is that the Application.yaml file is not resolved correctly in the configuration and the scope for access to Dynamics is not sent in the OAuth2 handshake. This means that the user is not authorized for the Dynamics client. This would also explain that the authorized client is not present. However, I do not know what is wrong in the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research and trying, I have now come to the solution.

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory:
    enabled: true
    profile.tenant-id: xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
    credential:
      client-id: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx
      client-secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    application-type: web-application
    authorization-clients:                
      **azure**:
        authorizationGrantType: **authorization_code**           
        scopes:
          https://xxxxxxx.crm4.dynamics.com/.default
```

is the right solution for the configuration

Comment: Do you happen to know the answer to this as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245865/copybatchrequestproperties-and-deleterequestcontainer-replacement-in-aspnetcore